# How to read my String correctly in html and mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I'm using MVC, getting a certain message this way

```
[HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Message(int ID) 
    {
        Models.Userr.Message model = new Models.User.Message();

        String getMessage = userService.getMessage(ID);
        model.Message = getMessage;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Then in the view I'm writting in the View:

```
<label>@Model.Message</label>
```

And it is writting in my screen, for example:

```
Hello <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>.
```

yet, it is being read as string. So my problem and question is:
what can I use in either MVC (in the controller) or Html (in the View) in order to detect the link.

Also 
I'm using the userservce.getMessage(int ID) to get a message related to a certain ID from a table of errors.

Comment: What does `what can I use in either MVC (in the controller) or Html (in the View) in order to detect the link.` mean?  Why do you need to detect the link? What if there are more then one link?  Additionally, as you've written the code it will *never* output your example, as I'm pretty sure you need to use `@Html.Raw(Model.Message)`.

Comment: I want to extract the URL from my string, that's all :)

Comment: For what purpose?  Extract the URL(s) from the Message is possible on both the server and the client, so the Purpose is important to answer the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I got what I wanted from @Html.Raw(Model.Message) . Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `Raw`

```
<label>@Html.Raw(Model.Message)</label>
```

This will write `Model.Message`'s contents as html instead of text.